# Backgroundworker Stops Working

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a WPF project that uses background workers to interfaces with some external hardware (Test & Measure equipment, etc), write to local files, and insert data into a database as it runs.  Program flow is basically sequential, the background workers in use are to keep the GUI accessible for the user, and were chosen because I haven't had issues with using them before.  We take measurements, do some stuff, log, then repeat.  There is a status log on the GUI that displays messages as we go.

All of this works beautifully for hours on end, however, eventually, without fail, it appears that the background worker used to write to the database never calls DoWork.

```
BackgroundWorker DbLogWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
...
DbLogWorker.DoWork +=
    new DoWorkEventHandler(DbLogWorker_DoWork);
DbLogWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
    new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        DbLogWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

ProcessScanData is called when data has been retrieved from one of the pieces of hardware, setting a property and firing a generic property changed event

(disclaimer: some extra code everywhere as I was investigating to see whats going on):

```
private void Data_DataSetChanged(object pSender, EventArgs pArgs)
{
    this.Test.ProcessScanData(OsaVm.Osa.Data.DataSet);
}

...
public void ProcessScanData(SortedList<double,double> pData)
{
    ...
    RaiseLogEvent(MessageType.SystemGeneral, "Logging to database...");
    DbLogWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new AsyncDbLogArgs(CurrentChannel, tempdate,
        loss1, loss2, loss3,
        CurrentTemperature, CurrentPressure, CurrentRoomTemp));
}

private void DbLogWorker_DoWork(object pSender, DoWorkEventArgs pArgs)
{
    AsyncDbLogArgs args = (AsyncDbLogArgs)pArgs.Argument;

    string filename = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        long datakey = Db.LogScan(CurrentChannel, args.Time,
            args.Temperature, args.Pressure, args.RoomTemperature,
            args.Loss1, args.Loss2, args.Loss3);
        filename = args.Time.ToString(FOLDER_DATETIME_FORMAT) + "_[" +    datakey.ToString() + "]";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        filename = args.Time.ToString(FOLDER_DATETIME_FORMAT) + "_{" + (fileindex++) + "}";
    }

    pArgs.Result = new Tuple<AsyncDbLogArgs, string>(args, filename);

}
```

**Symptoms:**
Everything works fine for anywhere between 1 hour and ~16 hours until eventually we get to a point where we see "Logging to database..." and nothing else ever happens.  No more messages, no exceptions (release build on target machine), no database entry...etc.  This happens consistently.

I've been scratching my head on this for a while.  Any leads will help, I have some workarounds in mind but I'd really like to know whats going on so I can avoid this in the future.

Thanks

Edited back to original code...thought the most recent would help avoid some "how do you know its not firing" questions

Comment: Well, remove the tons of empty catch blocks for starters.  That's a great way to have a program that doesn't crash, but doesn't work, and doesn't provide any indication of what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but many of those try catches were added after this problem came up, I'll edit back to the original code if it helps

Comment: Why NullReferenceException,because I cant see any NullReferenceException to get occured

Comment: Edited back to the original to show that they aren't relevant

Comment: I'd start adding more logging (e.g. DbLogWorker_DoWork and inside Db.LogScan()). Basically I see two possibilities: 1. deadlock in you code or the code you are calling. 2. you accidently pulled yourself a leg (e.g. remove eventhandler of backgroundworker etc..)

Comment: I have logging in Db.LogScan() before and after connection is established, as well as before and after the query is sent.  I have placed multiple logs in DbLogWorker_DoWork() while investigating, including right at the beginning of the function - "Logging to database..." is still the last message we see when this problem occurs.  Otherwise we see each message and things move along as intended.

Comment: Did you add a log entry *after*  the `Db.LogScan` call inside `DbLogWorker_DoWork`? I.e., does `Db.LogScan` ever return when there is a problem?

Comment: I have, however when there is a problem, and I also place a log entry right at the start of DbLogWorker_DoWork before doing anything else, it will not display either.  On the SQL server logs there appears to be no indication of an error or even an attempt to write at the time of failure

Comment: FYI, removed the background worker and moved the code to a function, its been running for more than 2 days with +400 records and 0 problems.  This works for now as it isn't totally awful having that code block the UI, but what the heck was going on?